# Custom annotationview not displaying in MKMapView in iOS 12

Tags: ios, objective-c, mapkit, mkmapview

I have a custom annotation view class which is like

```c
@interface MyAnnotationView : MKAnnotationView

@property (nonatomic, strong) UIImageView *imageView;

@end
```

and then I use it in the MKMapView like :

```c
- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id<MKAnnotation>)annotation
{
    MKAnnotationView *annotationView = nil;
    MyAnnotationView *view = (MyAnnotationView *)[mapView dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:MyAnnotationViewIdentifier];
    if (view == nil) {
        view = [[MyAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:MyAnnotationViewIdentifier];
    }
    view.imageView.image = myImage;
    annotationView = view;
    return annotationView;
}
```

This code works as expected till iOS 11, but in iOS 12 I dont see the image anymore. What am I missing? Any tips appreciated.

Comment: please check your MyAnnotationView object is nil or is allocated

Comment: `viewForAnnotation ` method is called?

Comment: Yes the image exist with no issues. the method is called. If I do the inspection in Xcode that is the layers, I see it fine with no issues but not in the app! I am out of my wits figuring this out.